# How to apply tag to Cloud Posse TF lambda-function module's child resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl, terraform-cloud

In TF Cloud I define an AWS Lambda like so

```
module "lambda-function" {
  source  = "cloudposse/lambda-function/aws"
  version = "0.5.1"
    
  environment = var.environment
   
  function_name = "${local.service_name}-${var.environment}-restart"
  description   = "AWS lambda to restart ${local.service_name}-${var.environment}"
    
  handler          = "handler"
  runtime          = "go1.x"
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda.output_path
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda.output_path)
    
  cloudwatch_logs_retention_in_days = 7
  timeout = 60
    
  vpc_config = {
    security_group_ids = tolist([data.aws_vpc.selected.id]),
    subnet_ids         = tolist(data.aws_subnets.selected.ids)
  }
}
```

but the corporate sentinel policy demands the following

```
    module.lambda-function.aws_iam_role.this[0] has tags_all with value 
    {Owner: Backend, Repo: https://github.com/xxx Service: xxx-service, Terraform: true, Environment: xxx-service-deploy-dev} 
    that is missing the required items [Name] from the list: [Name, Environment, Owner, Terraform]
```

I can't work out how to apply this tag to this child resource. I tried something like this, but it doesn't really make sense

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role_tags" {
  name = module.lambda-function.role_name
    
  # Add the desired tags here
  tags = {
    Name = "a tag"
  }
}
```

Is it possible, or must I get the policy changed?

EDIT:
We already use `default_tags` as suggested, but I don't want to add the same `Name` tag to all my resources. I need to add, usually I add a unique `Name` tag to individual resources.

```
provider "aws" {
  # ... other configuration ...
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      Owner       = "Backend"
      Repo        = "https://github.com/xxx"
      Service     = "xxx-service"
      Terraform   = true
      Environment = "xxx-service-deploy-dev"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  ...
  tags = {
    "Name" = "${var.stage}-${local.service_name}-task"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, there is no way to manage the tag for that resource outside of where the resource is created (the module) and since there are no tags being assigned in the module, there is no way to assign a tag. I suggest simply not using this module, and placing the resource code directly in your own terraform files instead.

Comment: Sad times :( Ok, thanks for sharing this info, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the module [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/lambda-function/aws/latest/examples/complete?tab=inputs) it looks like you can use `additional_tag_map`.

Or even `tag` [by looking at the code](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-lambda-function/blob/main/context.tf#L172C5-L172C5).